# Mounting of USB drive within rc.local works only until I log-in

Tags: usb, boot, mount

This worked prior to current upgrade.

Here's my `rc.local` (fragment):

```
date > /tmp/rc.log
sleep 20
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/sg3t/
df >> /tmp/rc.log
sleep 10
df >> /tmp/rc.log
```

after login, `rc.log` shows the drive properly mounted both `df` outputs, yet `df` shows it's no longer mounted once I login or SSH in.

Within the file manager giu tool, I have automount of insertable drives disabled.

After login, I can `sudo mount` as above and it works; but the drive is needed
permanently, not per login.

I also tried `fstab`; but I must have it wrong as the system booted into protected mode.

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/sg3t vfat defaults 0 0
```

I also tried `fuseblk` as `fs-type` (it's what `df -T` returns), same boot fail.

suggestions/corrections?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the fascination with using `rc.local` to mount a drive, but it *should* work as long as you remember there are two different users involved: the root user for rc.local, and you (whoever you are, you didn't say). [Here's a link that discusses this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/run-a-script-in-boot-as-user-using-etc-rc-local-4175560332/), but I haven't tried it.

I typically operate as user `pi`, and I make an entry in `fstab` for my 16 GB SanDisk USB drive. Here's what I do:

`man fstab`, and read it... In perusing `man fstab`, some of the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) available online and [advice](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=205016) on `fstab` that's published, we soon recognize there are some decisions to be made - options to be selected. There are six (6) fields in a `fstab` entry. Let's do them in order:

1. `fs_spec`  This is the most critical field. The oft-used specifications here are device node (e.g. `/dev/sda1`), `LABEL` and `UUID`. There are several other specs, but these 3 are sufficient for now. [Some advocate](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=205016) using the `UUID` spec and point out that it is more unique and therefore safer than the device node. But we're going to use the `LABEL` specification, and here's why: **We can set it; we have control over the value of `LABEL`, whereas we have no control over the so-called `UUID`.** In fact, for all types of `FAT` partitions, they do not have a true `UUID`. The identifier shown as `UUID` by `lsblk --fs` isn't actually a `UUID` at all! This is a rather murky back alley.
2. `fs_file`  This is mount point we used earlier; in our case: `/home/pi/mntThumbDrv`
3. `fs_vfstype`  This is the file system type of the drive (or partition) to be `mount`ed: `vfat`
4. `fs_mntops`  A comma-separated list of options. We'll use: `rw,user,nofail` (no spaces) which will tell the OS that the drive is read & write, users may mount the drive, and no error will be flagged if the device is not present at boot time (and stop the boot process!).
5. `fs_freq`  A flag that determines if the file system will be `dump`ed; `0` for our case
6. `fs_passno`  A flag that determines if the file system will be checked by `fsck`, and the order it's to be checked; `0` for our case

After working our way through all the fields, our `fstab` entry looks like this:

```
LABEL=SANDISK16GB /home/pi/mntThumbDrv vfat rw,user,nofail 0 0
```

Try this, and let us know if you run into issues. You may also wish to take a look at [my GitHub page for more technical drivel on this subject](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/edit/master/ExternalDrives.md). Also, keep in mind that much of this is now done under control of `systemd` instead of `mount`, but AFAIK the role of `fstab` and the functionality of mounting a disk is similar to `mount`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `fuseblk` is how NTFS drives look in `mount` output. Hence the suggestion to use `ntfs` option in `fstab`:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/sg3t ntfs defaults 0 0
```

If you insist on your `rc.local` solution, you can try to prevent the system from fiddling with your mounts by uninstalling the `udisks2` package. Obviously, don't expect the system to auto-mount anything after you do.

Alternatively, you can keep `udisks2` and use it to mount your disk from `rc.local`:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2
```

Comment: yes, apparently fuseblk means ntfs, fstab automount works correctly now.   thanks and thanks for the udisk2 info, also potentially helpful.